# SciKit Learn Train_Test Split Imbalance

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to train a classification model and am getting strong imbalance on my train_test split. I have tried several different random states. My entire sample has a breakdown of: `24/19/57` per class. There is definitely imbalance, but when I do the train_test split I am ending up with this breakdown: `5/0.1/94.9` per class. Does anyone have any insight into why this may be happening?

Here is what I have.

```
Text_train, Text_test, label_train, label_test = \
train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state = 42)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Reproducible example?  Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Here's the confusion matrix I am getting from it:                                                          [[ 1586   421   633]
 [   13    23    20]
 [11101  9536 29860]] This is off of a base of 50676/39900/122193

Comment: Reproducible means something other people can run.  I can't run your confusion matrix.  On a made up dataset of 100,000 elements, I am getting almost completely even split.

Comment: I'm not sure what else you want. I gave you everything you needed to reproduce the dataset. I gave you the split of the Label/DV by class and my code for the train_test_split. You didn't have the issue. I was just wondering why it could be happening to me.

Comment: `Text_train, Text_test, label_train, label_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42, stratify=y)`